# How can i downgrade PHP version from 8.1 to 7.4 in AlmaLinux 8?

Tags: php-7.4

current PHP is 8.1, but i want to change it to 7.4.
following the step as : https://wiki.crowncloud.net/?How_to_Install_PHP_7_x_in_AlmaLinux_8#How+to+Install+PHP+7+x+in+AlmaLinux+8

while command: ''dnf module install php:remi-7.4''

Please find my error below:

Error: Transaction test error:
file /usr/bin/php from install of php-cli-7.4.33-10.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ea-php-cli-1.0.0-11.16.11.cpanel.x86_64

please help

please help me what going on this and how to fix it

Comment: The error is telling you the requested package (php-7.4) conflicts with an already installed package (php-cli). But installing PHP 7.4 is **TERRIBLE IDEA**, that version is no longer supported so any vulnerabilities it has will not be fixed anymore.